# How do I load data from an Input Field to another page, using jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to programming so I am asking for some help. I am sure this question has been answered regarding PHP. I just want to perform this function on basic HTML.

**HTML page 1**

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="Postcode_6203" id="Zip_Code" class="cat_textbox signup_input_main" />
    <input id="find_resta_btn" class="cat_button search_rest_1" type="submit"/>
```

**HTML page 2**

```
<div id="zip_code_container">

</div>
```

How can I do this using AJAX and JQuery

I would submit my sample script I wrote, but I don't want to confuse anyone with it, because it did't work.

Comment: It might be appropriate to write a cookie on the first page and read its value on your second page? Either that are you could potentially pass the value in the querystring?

Comment: Can't really do this with ajax or jQuery. Both are for one page that is already loaded... When you submit the form with that input, it will send a GET request to wherever you send the form. Send the form to the other page, and you can probably use JS to parse the GET info from the URL

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
or
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
     var $name = $("#name_input_id").val();
     var $location = $("#location_input_id").val();
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "some.php",
       data: { name: $name, location: $location }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
```